# Readonly observable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, observable, readonly

I'm using typescript with knockout.js. And for one case I need immutable field for my class. This field should be observable.

I've created

```
readonly _isDirty = ko.observable<boolean>(false);
```

Assign value in constructor

```
constructor(data: ITypedInput, isDirty: any) {
    super(ko.unwrap(data));
    this._isDirty = isDirty;
}
```

But when I want to set another value

```
this._isDirty(true);
```

TypeScript compiler didn't say anything, that it is not allowed.
In another case, when I just set value like

```
this._isDirty = true;
```

Compiler said

> Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property.

So is there any way to have readonly observable?

Thanks.

Comment: would creating a `computedObservable` without a `write` callback solve your purpose? Because as Nitzan mentioned, `observable` is just a `function` which is called with a parameter to update its value, while for reading the current value you just have to call it without a parameter`

Comment: Having a `readonly` observable is a bit paradoxical... The point behind making an observable is that you can change it and updates happen automatically. If you don't want to change it, you might as well use "just" a `readonly` boolean: ordinary values work perfectly well when you `applyBindings`.

Answer (score 1):

Readonly means that you can not change the reference of the variable, it does not mean that you can't change the object itself.

For example:

```
class A {
    public readonly arr: any[] = [];
}

let a = new A();
a.arr = []; // error Cannot assign to 'arr' because it is a constant or a read-only property
a.arr.push(4); // fine
```

if `this._isDirty` is a function then you can invoke it even if the property is set to `readonly`.

Comment: So, answer is No, I can't make observable immutable?

Comment: You can, but that only means that you can not assign another observable instance into the same instance. But no, you can not guard against changing the observable state. You can create your own observable which does that